# Send messages with timer

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm writing a remind bot with the bot connector which reminds me when a subscribed youtube channel uploads a new video. I'm already able to get the latest release. But I need to check in intervals if there is a new video and send the link as a message.
What is the best way to send a message after a specific interval?

Comment: your title literally answers your question

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the SendMessage call as you won't be replying to an existing message.

http://docs.botframework.com/connector/new-conversations/#navtitle

As for setting up the interval, there are many ways to do this.  If you are azure you might check out:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var timer = new Timer();
   timer.Elapsed += GetLatestVideo;
   timer.Enabled = true;
   timer.Interval = 1000;
   timer.Start();
}

private static void GetLatestVideo(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // check video

    // if video != latestVideo
        // latestVideo = video
        // send message
}
```

You're going to want to store the `ConnectorClient` and the latest video in a variable on the class that contains this code, for better performance. But this is how you can add an interval.